# Concept of inserting ansatz - separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In my textbook it says write the unknown function of two variables as a product of two functions of a single variable u(x, t) = X(x) T (t) but then the second step it goes straight away to have T ̈(t)/T(t)= X ′′ (x) / X(x). Does it implies that the outcome of differentiate u(x,t) twice with respect to x is always equals to differentiate u(x,t) twice with respect to t?

Edit:

Thanks for the answer from @ Hans Lundmark. However in the following question why does the solution suggest it is T./((k^2)T)=X"/X rather than T ̈(t)/((k^2)T(t))= X ′′ (x) / X(x)?Does the question gives any hint on that?
[image]

Comment: If the equation that you're trying to solve is $u_{xx}=u_{tt}$, yes.

Comment: @HansLundmark Can you please explain a little bit more on this question?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, it depends on the equation that you are solving.  Let's work out what happens in the problem in your edit.

Let $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$.  Then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = X(x) T'(t)$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}= X''(x) T(t)$.    Substituting these into the differential equation
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},$$
we obtain
$$X(x)T'(t) = k^2X''(x)T(t).$$  Now, the idea of separation of variables is to manipulate this equation so that only $x$ variables are on one side (say the right side) and only $t$ variables are on the other side (say the left).  So, we will divide both sides by $X(x)$ and also divide both sides by $k^2 T(t)$.  This gives
$$\frac{T'(t)}{k^2 T(t)} = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am confused when should I need to differentiate the u(x,t) once or twice.

Comment: The number of times you differentiate $u(x,t)$ depends on the equation. For the equation that you posted, it says that you need to take one derivative with respect to t and you also need two derivatives with respect to x.